# Want to insert into secondary table wtih foreign keys but not in primary when name is the same

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am still pretty new to sqlite3 and I was learning about constraints and thought I would be useful to use for something I'm doing.

My main table has the name of the user. A secondary table that has messages and a foreign key that corresponds to the ID of the user who sent it.

I want to list all the users that have sent messages so far but I came across a problem where when querying by doing:

```
db.query(USER_TABLE, new String[] {_id, name}, null, null, null, null, null}
```

I get repeated users (name listed as many times as that user sent a message).
This seems to be an insertion problem. I do two inserts: one for the user to the user table and one for the message in the message table.

My goal is to see upon receiving the message to see if the user has already submitted a message so I don't keep inserting a user already in the database. However, I still want to insert the message along foreign key corresponding to the user already in the database.

I tried using `UNIQUE(name)` when creating my user table however that restricts the message from being added as well. Also tried using insertOrThrow but no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the user's ID for the message row, so you cannot avoid querying the user table. If you don't find the user, you know you must insert a new row:

```
void insertMessage(string user, string message) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            long id = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db,
                        "SELECT _id FROM Users WHERE Name = ?",
                        new String[]{ user });
            if (id == -1) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("Name", user);
                id = db.insert("Users", null, cv);
            }

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("UserID", id);
            cv.put("Text", message);
            db.insert("Messages", null, cv);

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that did it! One last question I have: why use DatabaseUtils & longforQuery rather than doing a regular query or a rawQuery with a string of the query definied? Is it just a preference thing?

Comment: True, constantly typing nulls get annoying. Didn't know DatabaseUtils was a thing! Thanks very much.